# Select row from set of rows based on the given condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table on SQL Server that contains sets of rows which are based on a "Key1" column. Below is the example of a few of such sets.

```
create  table myTable
(Key1 int,
Cond1 varchar(10),
Cond2 varchar(10),
Cond3 varchar(10),
Value int)

create table #temp
(Key1 int,
Value int)

insert into myTable values
(3, 'CT', 'IND' , 'INR', 6372),
(3, '', 'USA' , 'USD', 5732),
(3, '', '' , 'RUB', 7593),
(3, '', '' , '', 1045),
(5, '', '' , '', 9452),
(5, 'XU', 'ITA' , 'LIR', 6472),
(7, '', 'CAN' , 'CAD', 2845),
(7, '', '' , 'YEN', 8352)

| Key1 |  Cond1 |  Cond2  |  Cond3  |  Value  |
|------|--------|---------|---------|---------|
|   3  |   CT   |   IND   |   INR   |  6372   |
|   3  |        |   USA   |   USD   |  5732   |
|   3  |        |         |   RUB   |  7593   |
|   3  |        |         |         |  1045   |
|   5  |        |         |         |  9452   |
|   5  |   XU   |   ITA   |   LIR   |  6472   |
|   7  |        |   CAN   |   CAD   |  2845   |
|   7  |        |         |   YEN   |  8352   |
```

I need to select Key and Value columns for each unique "Key1" column based on the below priority list.

1. If all three cond1, cond2 and cond3 are present, pick corresponding value.
2. If cond1 is blank, and cond2 and cond3 are present, pick that vale.
3. if cond1, cond2 are blank and cond3 is present, pick corresponding value.
4. If all conditions are blank, pick corresponding value.
5. Note that cond1 exists only when cond2 and cond3 exist. Similarly cond2 exists only when cond3 already exists.

So the final output should look like below

```
|  Key1  |  Value  |
|-------|---------|
|   3   |  6372   |
|   5   |  6472   |
|   7   |  2845   |
```

One way to achieve is to put 4 different select queries.

```
insert into #temp
select Key1, Value from myTable 
where cond1 <> '' and cond2 <> '' and cond3 <> ''

insert into #temp
select m.Key1, m.Value from myTable m  
left outer join #temp t
on m.Key1= t.Key1
where cond1 = '' and cond2 <> '' and cond3 <> ''
and t.Key1 is null

insert into #temp
select m.Key1, m.Value from myTable m  
left outer join #temp t
on m.Key1= t.Key1
where cond1 = '' and cond2 = '' and cond3 <> ''
and t.Key1 is null

insert into #temp
select m.Key1, m.Value from myTable m  
left outer join #temp t
on m.Key1= t.Key1
where cond1 = '' and cond2 = '' and cond3 = ''
and t.Key1 is null
```

But this requires a lot of code. I am wondering if there is any better way to achieve it?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you want to achieve here. If you could [edit] your question to include proper sample data and desired results it would very much help us to help you. For more information, read the [sql server tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info).

Comment: @ZoharPeled, ThomA Added DDL queries, expected output and other details. Thanks.

Comment: Are rows with values only in Cond1, Cond2 (leaving Cond3 empty) possible, and if so, where should they be ranked in the priority?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Nope, cond1 exists only when cond2 and cond3 exist. Similarly cond2 exists only when cond3 already exists. (Added to question).

Answer (score 0):

If "blanks" mean null values then use logic as is. Otherwise convert to `<> ''`:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by key1 order by
            case
                when cond1 is not null and cond2 is not null and cond3 is not null then 1
                when cond2 is not null and cond3 is not null then 2
                when cond3 is not null then 3
                else 4
            end) as rn
)
select * from data where rn = 1;
```

If you equivalently need to know the first not null column and "condition" values can't be duplicated both of these should also work as shorter versions:

```
case
    when cond1 is not null then 1
    when cond2 is not null then 2
    when cond3 is not null then 3
    else 4
end

case coalesce(cond1, cond2, cond3)
    when cond1 then 1 when cond2 then 2 when cond3 then 3 else 4 end
```

Or possibly, if you want to rely on null propagation and string collation. This would most likely be frowned on in a review but it's fun and instructive as an exercise:

```
coalesce('1' + cond1, '2' + cond2, '3' + cond3, '4')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `distinct`, [`first_value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and `case` to get the results you want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Key1, 
  FIRST_VALUE([Value]) OVER(PARTITION BY Key1 ORDER BY 
  CASE 
      WHEN Cond1 <> '' THEN 1 -- can only happen if Cond2 and Cond3 have values 
      WHEN Cond2 <> '' THEN 2 -- can only happen if Cond3 has a value 
      WHEN Cond3 <> '' THEN 3 
      ELSE 4
  END
  )
FROM myTable
```